# Access images, create contacts and restore images

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I wan't to do this using Mono, but Mono is so transparent the question is really regarding the Android & iOS API.

I want to do the following:

- Read all contacts, send to server
- Read all available images in the gallery, send to server
- Download contacts from server, restore to contacts
- Download images from server, restore to gallery

Now, i know i can read the contacts from both iOS and Android. The rest im not so sure about. Is it possible to get all the images from the gallery? Is it possible to create contacts programmaticly? Is it possible to create images and store to gallery programmaticly?

I am interested in doing the mentioned for both iOS and Android! Is i possible?
It is perfectly fine if the app prompts the user to get full acces to mentioned librarys (contacts and gallery).

Comment: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/recipes/Data/ContentProviders/Read_Contacts

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions in a single item - also try searching first, accessing Contacts and Images are common questions that have been discussed multiple times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a unified API across both iOS and Android, you should investigate the [Xamarin.Mobile API](http://xamarin.com/mobileapi).

They cover contacts already, and you should [submit a request for them to consider a general photo gallery API](https://docs.google.com/a/xamarin.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dFBlbEtBZmZaT3pIYnBTRHZOQWV4cFE6MQ)--makes sense that developers would want a cross-platform way to work with it as well.

Comment: The Mobile API actually includes a Media namespace with some classes to provide access to the gallery of each platform.